# Увеличивается размер блока с применением font-weight

Tags: css, css3, html5

Допустим, у меня есть блок с текстом. Я хочу, чтобы при наведении на этот блок изменялся font-weight и при этом **не изменял размеры блока.** Я попробовал применить box-sizing - не работает.

Comment: ну так текст же физически меняет размер...занчит увеличте сам блок изначально, чтобы после изменения тоже влезал

Comment: Или найдите шрифт который не меняет ширину при изменении жирности. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniwidth_typeface